# Magento2 How can we set 2 layout?

Tags: magento2, layout

- When we create a product via admin by default product-full-width is set under Design > Layout > Product Full Width
- When we are importing products it is not set so we need to set it via XML
- I tried to set it from catalog_product_view.xml(I tried from both folders layout & page_layout) but it is allowing me to set only 1 layout (1 Column or product-full-width). How can we set both?

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no option for Product-full-width in default.
So did you create new layout with product-full-width?

You need to set the layout with "product-full-width" in theme/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product.view.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="product-full-width" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: page-layout-1column page-layout-product-full-width => I need to add the second page-layout-product-full-width